# Multiple Spaces in log4j SMTP appender

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 in our Spring MVC application to send an email with the SMTP appender.  The default format of the email is HTML.  Part of the message we write is the HTTP request body (in this case JSON) which has been pretty printed.  When the email arrives all of the JSON data is slammed to the left margin (no indenting).  This is because log4j is not writing non-breaking spaces (nbsp).  Is there a way to make it do that?

I don't want to put them directly in the message because this data is also written to a file log and to a database table (which look fine).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the message contains HTML is because you configure log4j to use [`HTMLLayout`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.java#305), otherwise it would default to `text/plain` message.

I guess your best bet is configuring the appender to use `PatternLayout`

```
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.email.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't LOOK as nice.  If the formatter is HTML then shouldn't it know how to substitute in an nbsp or allow you to wrap the message in a <pre> tag or something?  I guess the concept that the message is itself formatted is a little odd.

Comment: So write your own `Layout` and wrap the whole message inside `<pre>`. I wonder why you don't like a simple `text/plain` message